What is the maximum possible delta v we could achieve from assembling a chemical rocket in orbit (not launching a final stage from the ground)?
To clarify, this is about an orbital assembly. I am not asking the maximum weight of launch vehicles or anything relating to that.
This is a pure hypothetical scenario in which we have an infinite budget and can send whatever we want into orbit at whatever cost with todays technology.
Theoretically lets say we had this infinite budget, and used all of the current launch vehicles and fuel tanks we have with modern tech for some arbitrary measure of propellant assembled in orbit like the ISS.
Lets say we are just trying to send a voyager-type probe to some far off location in deep space or perhaps interstellar space with similar weight and dimensions, but much faster including gravity assists.
Also lets include an arbitrary number of the highest ISP chemical rocket motors we currently have for an appropriate thrust-weight ratio.
What would be the maximum dV achievable by this hypothetical vehicle? and why?
I am trying to wrap my head around the tyranny of the rocket equation and exactly how it limits our currently usable technology.

Is this not a duplicate of the question asked yesterday? Usually the precedent is to edit questions rather than repost them.

@Der - can you explain why you deleted your original post and then wrote this exact copy? It looks like you were trying to evade a close vote, which is not acceptable behaviour

First time using this website but it literally says either wait for a review or post another modified version of the question, which i did appropriately modify. The closing of my question was interesting to begin with, as it was not at all related to whatever old question the original voters were claiming it was related to.
Cheers. @RoryAlsop

If you had waited, reopen votes were coming in. That would have been a better way to handle this. Never mind.

Even with an infinite budget you will still need to constrain the problem some more since the planet has finite resources. If you are happy with chemical rocket propulsion, then we can use the exhaust velocity of the RS-25, which is 4436 m/s in a vacuum. Let's assume a probe mass of 1000 kg, and the mass of the engine is 3,177 kg. Since you agreed to an infinite budget, we'll allocate 15% of that budget to perfecting single crystal graphene manufacturing and build giant propellant tanks out of that. This assumption, plus the square-cube law, allows us to make a "reasonable" engineering approximation - we will ignore the structural mass of the rocket.
Now we can use the bare-bones rocket equation...
$$m_0=m_{\rm f} \exp({\Delta}v/v_{\rm exhaust})$$
Or
$${\Delta}v = v_{\rm exhaust} \ln \left( {m_0 \over m_{\rm f}} \right)$$
If you converted all of the Earth's oceans into propellant and launched it into space with a mass driver, your $m_0$ value could be as high as
$1.4 \times 10^{21}$ kg. So the delta-v you could achieve would be
$${\Delta}v = 4436\times \ln \left( {1.4 \times 10^{21} \over 1000+3177} \right) = 4436 \times 40.35 = 179,008~{\rm m/s}$$
This is about 0.06% of the speed of light.

And for comparison, that’s a mass of propellant equivalent to Charon, Pluto’s largest satellite (and 10% the mass of Pluto).

thank you so much this really helps me visualize the limits especially with the example of converting the oceans into propellant.
exactly what i was looking for.

You're welcome! It was a great question.

Did you account for the weight of the RS-25 engine? It weighs 3526 kilograms (about 3.5 metric tons, 7775 lbs). Generally if we're using graphene I'd say we can ignore fuel tank weight but an engine as efficient as the RS-25 will probably weigh around as much, which would at least quadruple your dry mass.

@controlgroup Yes, since the propellant mass is the mass of the world's oceans, the mass of the engine is pretty negligible right up until the very end of the burn.

@phil1008 the $\mathrm{d}v$ I calculate after adding that much extra payload mass is $\approx178652,\mathrm{m},\mathrm{s}^{-1}$, which isn't a huge change (6.6 km/s, about 3.6%) but is definitely still significant. Remember that, when burning at constant force, most of the acceleration happens at the end of the burn!

Fair point. I updated my answer.

I hope the budget is still large enough to get your RS-25 rated for 158 billion years of continuous operation...

Wow, did you actually calculate the burn time? If you did you should add that to the answer!

I actually attempted (albeit poorly) a calculation of a burn time using 1000000 RS25s, and without even accounting for the added weight of the engines, my figure still came up into the hundreds of millions of years. Is this correct?
